# How do clues in Max Payne affect gameplay?

Tags: max-payne-3

How do clues affect gameplay in Max Payne?  Do they change the story at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they do not affect the story. Some clues will have an effect on other clues, though, like meeting the same person for the second time.